# How to get Header Text and Detail text from Firemonkey TListView by Header textGlyphButton on ItemClickEx Event?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

On my `TListView` on `FireMonkey` having the `Header` appearence as "Custom", I need to get the header´s item text and detail text, on the `TListview.ItemExClick` event, when user click on the Header´s `TListItemTextButton`.

I have something like this...

```
   procedure TForm1.lv1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; ItemIndex: 
    Integer;
      const LocalClickPos: TPointF; const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
   begin
     if ItemObject is TListItemTextButton then
     begin
       if TListItemTextButton(ItemObject).Text = '-' then
       begin
         TListItemTextButton(ItemObject).Text := '+';
         //Do something with header´s text   
       end
       else if TListItemTextButton(ItemObject).Text = '+' then
       begin
         TListItemTextButton(ItemObject).Text := '-';
         //Do something with header´s text
       end;
     end;
    end;
```

Any clues?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: `TListView(Sender).Items[ItemIndex].Text` and `TListView(Sender).Items[ItemIndex].Detail`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but That doesn´t work. It get´s the first header when no "detail" item is selected, even when clicking on the second header´s button, and when a detail is selected, it get´s me the detail text.

Comment: I should say that I´m using Delphi 10.2.1 Tokyo.

Comment: Victoria, your tip didn´t worked out on ItemClickEx Event, but it worked on OnButtonClick Event. I splitted the code in two parts and worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event OnItemCkick doesn´t work for the header.
So, the easyest way, is to use a TTextButton insted.